# Let $A=(4,10] \cup \{1, 14, 27 \}$. Find, with proof, the interior point of $A$; that is, $A^o$, in $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Let $A=(4,10] \cup \{1, 14, 27 \}$. Find, with proof, the interior point of $A$; that is, $A^0$, in $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric.

**EDIT**

**Attempt:** I claimed that $A^0 = (4,10)$. Here's what I tried.

1. Let $x \in (4,10)$ be arbitrary. Choose $r = \min\{x-4, 10-x\}>0$. The goal is to show that $B(x,r) \subseteq A$. Now, let $y \in B(x,r)$ be arbitrary. We have
   \begin{align*}
   |y-x|<r &\iff -r < y-x < r \\
   &\iff x-r < y < x+r \\
   &\iff 4 = x-(x-4) \le x-r < y < x+r \le x+(10-x) = 10.
   \end{align*}
   Hence, $y \in A$, and so, $B(x,r) \subseteq A$. Therefore, $(4,10) \subseteq A^0$.
2. For $x=1$, given any $r>0$, we always have $B(x,r) \nsubseteq A$. Indeed, by taking $a=1+r_1$, where $r_1=\min\left\{\frac 12, \frac r2 \right\}>0$, we have $a \in B(1,r)$, but $a \notin A$.
3. For $x=10$, given any $r>0$, we always have $B(x,r) \nsubseteq A$. Indeed, by taking $a=10+r_1$, where $r_1=\min\left\{\frac 12, \frac r2 \right\}>0$, we have $a \in B(10,r)$, but $a \notin A$.
4. For $x=14$, given any $r>0$, we always have $B(x,r) \nsubseteq A$. Indeed, by taking $a=14+r_1$, where $r_1=\min\left\{\frac 12, \frac r2 \right\}>0$, we have $a \in B(14,r)$, but $a \notin A$.
5. For $x=27$, given any $r>0$, we always have $B(x,r) \nsubseteq A$. Indeed, by taking $a=27+r_1$, where $r_1=\min\left\{\frac 12, \frac r2 \right\}>0$, we have $a \in B(27,r)$, but $a \notin A$.
6. Notice that $A^0 \subseteq A$; indeed, because $x \in B(x,r)$ and $B(x,r) \subseteq A$, then $x \in A$. So, by taking the contraposition, if $x \notin A$, then $x \notin A^o$.

Thus, $(4,10) = A^0$, as claimed.

Does the above correct? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is not only correct, but also very clearly written. One minor thing you can do to shorten it. Because points 2,3,4,5 all basically use the same idea, I wouldn't write them as separate points. Instead, I would replace

> 2. For $x=1$, given any $r>0$, we always have $B(x,r) \nsubseteq A$. Indeed, by taking $a=1+r_1$, where $r_1=\min\left\{\frac 12, \frac r2
>    > \right\}>0$, we have $a \in B(1,r)$, but $a \notin A$.
> 3. For $x=10$, given any $r>0$, we always have $B(x,r) \nsubseteq A$. Indeed, by taking $a=10+r_1$, where $r_1=\min\left\{\frac 12, \frac r2
>    > \right\}>0$, we have $a \in B(10,r)$, but $a \notin A$.
> 4. For $x=14$, given any $r>0$, we always have $B(x,r) \nsubseteq A$. Indeed, by taking $a=14+r_1$, where $r_1=\min\left\{\frac 12, \frac r2
>    > \right\}>0$, we have $a \in B(14,r)$, but $a \notin A$.
> 5. For $x=27$, given any $r>0$, we always have $B(x,r) \nsubseteq A$. Indeed, by taking $a=27+r_1$, where $r_1=\min\left\{\frac 12, \frac r2
>    > \right\}>0$, we have $a \in B(27,r)$, but $a \notin A$.

with a much shorter and just as clear:

> 3. For $x\in\{1, 10, 14, 27\}$, given any $r>0$, we always have $B(x,r) \nsubseteq A$. Indeed, by taking $a=x+\min\{\frac12, \frac r2\}$, we have $a \in B(x,r)$, but $a \notin A$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciated your comment. Now, what about $x$ that not equals to all the above? Such as $x<1, x>27$, etc? Do all of them need to be considered? Could we use the same idea as before?

Comment: @krewlpt Strictly speaking you’re right, but you can just start the proof by mention that the interior of a set is a subset of the set.

Comment: @krewlpt (Because the ball around $x$ will contain $x$ itself, so $x$ must be in $A$)

Comment: @Milten Yes, indeed. But, where I got confused in is, does $x>27$ need to be considered as before?

Comment: @krewlpt You can consider them by saying they can’t be in the interior because they’re not even in $A$. But I would hardly mention it - that property should be implicit knowledge in my mind

Comment: @Milten What about a proof by contradiction? For $1<x<4$, suppose that $x \in A^0$. Then, there exists $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq A$. Notice that $x \in B(x,r)$ for any $r>0$. By assumption, we have $x \in A$. But, $x$ is clearly not contained in $A$ by definition of $A$, contradiction. Hence, $x$ is not an interior point of $A$.

Comment: @krewlpt Like Milten said, you can add a sentence about how if $x\notin A$, then $x\notin A^o$ because $A^o\subseteq A$.

Comment: @5xum Aah, I see. Since $A^0 \subseteq A$, then if $x \in A^0$, we have $x \in A$. By taking the contraposition, if we take $x \notin A$, then $x \notin A^0$, doesn't it?

Comment: @krewlpt Exactly.